# Get collection of elements from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nashorn, jjs

I have a JSON file with the structure as below:

```
{"root" : {
     "parent" : {
          "childA" : 
              ["element1",
               "element2"],
          "childB" :
              ["element1",
               "element2"]
     }
}
```

How can I get a collection of children `[childA, childB]` from it?

For now what I'm doing:

1. Parse the JSON file to an object (I know how to do that and suggested response is about this).
2. Create the collection:

   ```
   var collection = [JSON.root.parent.childA, JSON.root.parent.childB];
   collection.forEach(function(child) {
       print(child[0])
   });
   ```

to print `"element1"`.

I'm new to JavaScript but I believe there is a better and more generic way to achieve the point 2.

EDIT:
I forgot to add that this Java Script is used inside Nashorn jjs script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: `Object.keys(JSON.root.parent)`.

Comment: Don't use "JSON" as a variable name, you're at risk to override or shadow the native `window.JSON` object.

Comment: `var collection = Object.values(JSON.root.parent)`

Comment: @clinomaniac - Suggested topic is about parsing JSON string. My question is not about parsing JSON, but rather how to extract particular elements from the JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `Object.keys()` for this:

```js
var data = {"root" : {
     "parent" : {
          "childA" : 
              ["element1",
               "element2"],
          "childB" :
              ["element1",
               "element2"]
     }
   }
};
var collection = [];
for (var childIndex in data.root.parent){
  data.root.parent[childIndex].every(child => collection.push(child));
};
console.log(collection);
```

Comment: This returns keys only, so for `console.log(child[0]` I have output `childA` not `element1`

Comment: This works for me... kind of. I like @Musa answer more, but it doesn't work inside of a jjs script.

Comment: "*Simply use Object.keys() for this*" ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` to get the entries in the parent object.

```js
var data = {"root" : {
     "parent" : {
          "childA" : 
              ["element1",
               "element2"],
          "childB" :
              ["element1",
               "element2"]
     }
   }
};


var collection = []; 
for (var o in data.root.parent){
    collection.push(data.root.parent[o]);
}
collection.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child[0]);
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add that this code is running as jjs Nashorn script and for some reasons it doesn't recognise `Object.values` as a valid function, but your code is actually what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JToken also -

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;    

 JToken.Parse(response.Content)
.SelectTokens("root.parent");
```